# Querying members of a specific list, who are not in a few specific data extensions, and who have opened/clicked in 180 days

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm almost certain there is a more efficient way to write this, but I can't seem to see how exactly. Would it be better to do the first query to populate a DE, and then run a 2nd query against that one to populate the final DE?

```sql
SELECT viewSub.subscriberkey, 
       viewSub.emailaddress, 
       viewSub.status, 
       viewSub.createddate, 
       viewSub.listid 
FROM   _listsubscribers viewSub 
       LEFT JOIN [programMembers] members 
              ON viewSub.emailaddress = members.primaryemail 
       LEFT JOIN [internalSeeds] seeds 
              ON viewSub.emailaddress = seeds.primaryemail 
       LEFT JOIN [controlGroup] control
              ON viewSub.emailaddress = control.[email address] 
WHERE  members.primaryemail IS NULL 
       AND seeds.primaryemail IS NULL 
       AND control.[email address] IS NULL 
       AND viewSub.listid = 93832 
       AND viewSub.status = 'Active'
       AND viewSub.subscriberkey IN (select Subscriberkey FROM _Open)
       OR viewSub.subscriberkey IN (select Subscriberkey FROM _Click)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks good to me. The only thing I would take out is

```
OR viewSub.subscriberkey IN (select Subscriberkey FROM _Click)
```

It might be redundant as an OPEN infers engagement and this step adds a computational expensive.

Depending on your list size, you might want to use Staging Tables as the queries will time out after 30 minutes, so breaking it into bits makes sense.

e.g combine members, controls and seeds into a new DE and then

```
SELECT viewSub.subscriberkey, 
       viewSub.emailaddress, 
       viewSub.status, 
       viewSub.createddate, 
       viewSub.listid 
FROM   _listsubscribers viewSub 
       LEFT JOIN [NewDEWithSeedMembersAndControl] New 
       ON viewSub.EmailAddress = new.orimaryemail
WHERE  new.primaryemail IS NULL  
       AND viewSub.listid = 93832 
       AND viewSub.status = 'Active'
       AND viewSub.subscriberkey IN (select Subscriberkey FROM _Open)
```

You also need to add a DateDiff in the WHERE for the 180 day engagement (right now you are looking at 6 months worth of data). You need to include a "Last Opened" column . I would advise adding this to the `[NewDEWithSeedMembersAndControl] New` query so the population in the DE represents 180 days engagement.

**UPDATE**

In your comments you ask for an understanding of the query performance. While alot of it is attributed to how the "SFMC Query Engine" handles queries, I found this article very helpful in building queries that run faster: [Logical Query Processing](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you)

Resources:

- [Optimize the Query Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/optimize_the_query_activity/)
- [Use Intermediate Tables to Optimiz](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/use_intermediate_tables_to_optimize_a_query/)e A Query

Comment: Breaking it into two queries absolutely worked. Out of curiosity, why is it that two queries, doing essentially the same tasks worked so much more quickly?

Comment: Read up logical query processing will update my answer

Comment: @ZacBrown updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the additional resources - I'll check them out and am sure they will be a huge help. And thanks again for the answer!